# xlwings unable to write to Excel when more than 37 rows

Tags: python, excel-formula, xlwings

I want to write an Array(40rows, 2 columns) to Excel with xlwings, but it can't work. Through a lot of trying, I find than when array's row is bigger than 36, it can't write to Excel.

Here is the code:

```
import xlwings as xw

data = [['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V405'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V405'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V405'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V405'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V405'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V405'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], [
'20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601']]
print(len(data))

app = xw.App(visible=False, add_book=False)
wb = app.books.add()
sht = wb.sheets["sheet1"]

sht.range("A2").value = data[0:37]
print(sht.range("A2").value)
wb.save("CS_PT_By_Tray.xlsx")
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

The above code can't write to Excel, but if I change

```
sht.range("A2").value = data[0:37]
```

to

```
sht.range("A2").value = data[0:36]
```

it does work.
How can that be?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are iterating through the elements in the array, right.  I just changed this line:

```
sht.range("A2").value = data[10:20]
```

I changed some of your data points too.

```
data = [['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T601'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T602'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T603'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T604'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T605'], ['20180714', 'B8A156WH4T606'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T607'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T608'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T609'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T6010'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T6011'], ['20180715', 'B8A156WH4T6012'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V4013'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V4014'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V4015'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V4016'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V4017'], ['20180715', 'B8A320WH5V4018'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V5019'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V5020'], [
'20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], ['20180715', 'B8A490QU5V504'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601'], ['20180716', 'B8A156FH4V601']]
```

I changed the ending numbers from 01 to 20.  Now, I run the script and get this.

[image]

Isn't that what you would expect?